# Consider the set system $G=\{(0,t):t>0\}.$ Show that the intervals $(0,2]$ and $[1,2]$ is in $\sigma(G)$

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:**

> Consider the set system $G=\{(0,t):t>0\}.$ Show that the intervals $(0,2]$ and $[1,2]$ is in $\sigma(G)$, where $\sigma(G)$ is the sigma-algebra generated by G.

**Thoughts:**

I'm thinking about showing that $G\subset \sigma(G)\subset \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ where $\mathscr{B}(R)$ is the Borel set of $\mathbb{R}.$

By showing this the intervals $(0,2]$ and $[1,2]$ will be elements of $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}).$

So by defining a function:
$$g:\{0\}\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},     g(0,t)=t$$
The pre image would be:
$$g^{-1}([0,\infty)$$
and it's known that $[0,\infty)=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}).$

It's known that $(0,2],[1,2]\in [0,\infty)=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}).$

Is this a wrong idea?

Comment: Is $\sigma(G)$ intended to be the sigma-algebra generated by $G$?

Comment: Oh yes, I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two observations that may help you to prove the claim from first principles. First, note that
$$
(0, 2] = \bigcap_{k \geq 1} (0, 2 + 1/k) .
$$
Second, note that
$$
[1, 2] = (0, 2] \setminus (0, 1) = (0, 2] \cap (0, 1)^c.
$$
Then, recall that elements of $\sigma(G)$ can be generated from elements of $G$ by countable intersections, unions, and/or complements.

Can you use these observations + definition of $\sigma(G)$ to conclude?

Comment: Thank you for the reply and thanks for the hints,@JKL.

I think what's catching me off guard is the whole $(0,t)$ part of the set. Can you help to elaborate on this? and how to understand it. Because we havn't really worked with two dimensions.

Comment: Can you expand more on what you mean by the whole $(0, t)$ part of the set? For example: $G$ is a set of all intervals of the form $(0, t)$, where $t > 0$. So it contains $(0, 1), (0, \pi)$, $(0, 100)$, etc.

Comment: Dont you mean $(0,2]=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(0,2-\frac{1}{n})$ ?

Comment: Your set is not quite right (and you should think about why the union is not right) -- but you are also right in that I also made a minor mistake which I fixed: I changed $(0, 2 - 1/k)$ to $(0, 2 + 1/k)$.

Comment: Now i makes perfect sense, thank you for all your help.